# Take picture using webcam from command line

Tags: api, command-line, webcam, image

I have a Logitech webcam (QuickCam Pro for Notebooks), and I'd like to take a snapshot using the cam from a command line.

Does it have any command line interface?

If not, is there an API that will allow me to build a command line tool like this?

Comment: *Which* command line are you talking about?

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: The question is ill specified, and may well be a "What software do I use?" type which belongs on SU rather than SO. Or not, but that depends on context we have not been given, and 12 hours are enough to expect the asker to clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to build such a command line application yourself. Basically you would use captureFromCam() to initialize the camera and then call QueryFrame() to capture a picture. Should be straightforward.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old discussion, but maybe you arrived here like I did recently looking for a simple command line app to capture a snapshot image from a webcam in Windows. If so, have a look at the following post on my blog:

http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/snapz-a-command-line-cam-image-grabber/

It's about a little program called snapz that I've just written to take a snapshot from a USB camera in a batch file. It's really basic - when you run it, it snaps a 640x480 image from the default video capture device (e.g. webcam) and saves it to the current directory. It's free and easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

The question itself is not programming related, just a request of some hardwares bundled softwares documentation.

I will answer the question as it WAS a programming question.

If you talking about webcams on a windows OS you can use DirectShow as in this example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx

Just create a console application in visual studio that takes some commandline parameters and let it use the code in the example and you are on your way.