# Camera trigger in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, triggers, camera

Anyone has an idea about how would be possible to trigger a usb camera and storage images without use Cheese or similar software, just comand lines / shell script or phyton script? Basically I would like to trigger my usb Cam every 1.72 seconds and store the pictures in a local folder. Using Ubuntu 22.04 here.

I have 2 integrated cameras and one external in a usb 3.0 port.

that's what `lsusb` shows:

```
root@aerial:/home/aerial# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 083: ID 413c:81b1 Dell Computer Corp. Dell Wireless 5809e Gobi™ 4G LTE Mobile Broadband Card
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:575f Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:8a8f Atmel Corp. Atmel maXTouch Digitizer
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5834 Broadcom Corp. 5880
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:576e Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_8M
**Bus 002 Device 055: ID 1b3f:2002 Generalplus Technology Inc. 808 Camera**
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take picture from webcam using linux command line (bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391456/take-picture-from-webcam-using-linux-command-line-bash)